SQL - substrings
I am working on a SQL query that reads from a SQLServer database to produce an extract file. One of the requirements is to remove the leading zeros (when exist) and the zeros between a suffix and the first non-zeros os significant numbers from some fields. So, for example,

"00000123" needs to return "123"
"AA000345" needs to return "AA345"

Is there a way in SQL to easily remove those 0s?
Thanks in advance :)
I have tried some of the solutions proposed in these threads:

Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement
Better techniques for trimming leading zeros in SQL Server?


Which database? MySQL and SQL Server are very different products with different functions. There are very few functions common to both. In MySQL for example you can use regular expressions. SQL Server doesn't have them and may get them in 2025

SQL Server, sorry about that

SQL is the language, not the database. Do you mean SQL Server ?

Why don't you just do a pass to clean up the data once, so you don't have to do this every time?

Please edit your title to get rid of the all-caps - that's generally regarded as equivalent to shouting.

@TimRoberts the OP would still need an efficient way to remove 0s. You can't clean 1K, much less 100K or 1M rows by hand. If the values are generated by applications, or if they're actually meaningful business values, you'll need a repeatable way to clean

In MySQL 8, private previews of Azure SQL and probably SQL Server 2025 (whenever that arrives) you can use REGEXP_REPLACE and a regular expression to replace 0s. Trimming leading 0s, perhaps REGEXP_REPLACE(field, ^0+',''). In current SQL Server versions it's easier to use a client language like Python either as a client script or through sp_execute_external_script`

What version of SQL Server are you using? Will the numeric part ever be all-zeros?  Will there ever be an alpha-only value or any combinations other than your samples?

what about AA0003405 ? What should this return ?

This can be done in several steps:

Find the location of the first digit. This can be done with PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',string).
Split the string into two parts using LEFT() to get the first part and STUFF() to remove the first part (simpler than RIGHT()). The left part might be empty.
Trim the leading zeros from the second part. If SQL Server 2022, you can use LTRIM(..., '0').
To handle the all-zeros case, the empty string can be converted to a 0 using a combination of NULLIF() and ISNULL().  A CASE expression could also be used.
Finally, join the two results.

Exception: If no digits are found, return the original string.
SELECT *
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', D.String), 0) AS Pos) P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        LEFT(D.String, P.POS - 1) AS LeftPart,
        STUFF(D.String, 1, P.POS - 1, '') AS RightPart
) LR
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LTRIM(LR.RightPart, '0') AS TrimmedRight
) T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(T.TrimmedRight, ''), '0') AS FixTrimmedRight
) F
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE WHEN P.Pos IS NULL
        THEN D.String
        ELSE CONCAT(LR.LeftPart, F.FixTrimmedRight)
        END AS Result
) R

The above calculates each step separately for demonstration purposes. The calculations can also be combined.
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN P.Pos IS NULL
        THEN D.String
        ELSE CONCAT(
                LEFT(D.String, P.POS - 1),
                ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(STUFF(D.String, 1, P.POS - 1, ''), '0'), ''), '0')
            )
        END AS Result
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', D.String), 0) AS Pos) P

Sample results:



String
Pos
LeftPart
RightPart
TrimmedRight
FixTrimmedRight
Result




00000123
1

00000123
123
123
123


AA000345
3
AA
000345
345
345
AA345


AA003045
3
AA
003045
3045
3045
AA3045


BB000000
3
BB
000000

0
BB0


00000000
1

00000000

0
0


ABCDEFGH
null
null
null
null
0
ABCDEFGH



If using an older version of SQL Server, you may need to do another PATINDEX('%[^0]%', RightPart) to find the first nonzero character and again apply STUFF(). Alternately, if you know the remainder is only numeric, you can convert to an integer and back to a string.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo

This query will get what you are after.
You only need the column4 , I put column1 to 3 to show you how it is build up.

In column1 I find where the first zero starts
in column2 I extract everything before the first zero
in column3 is everyting after the first zeros, and trimmed leading zeros
and finally in column4 we have the result, column2 + column 3

declare @v varchar(20) = 'AA000340501'
select patindex('%[0-9]%', @v),
       left(@v, patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) - 1),
       substring(right(@v, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) + 1), patindex('%[^0]%', right(@v, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) + 1) + '.'), len(right(@v, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) + 1))),
       left(@v, patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) - 1) + substring(right(@v, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) + 1), patindex('%[^0]%', right(@v, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) + 1) + '.'), len(right(@v, len(@v) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @v) + 1)))


result is



column1
column2
column3
column4




3
AA
340501
AA340501




It looks like the above will always trim two leading digits (zeros or not), regardless of the number of leading zeros. "AA123456" -> "AA3456", "AA000123" -> "AA0123".

@TN Yes you are right, I edited my answer and added a corrected query

Yes it possible you can replace '0' with ''
Select Replace('00000123', '0', '')
Select Replace('AA000345', '0', '')


I did not downvote, but what about AA0003405 this will come out as AA345 and I guess the op wants that as AA3405

Yeah, this solution is a bit too naive and will remove too many zeroes
